# Adding * .prj file to output via Python script tool that creates fishnet?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, vector-grid

I'm a new python user.

I wanted to make a tool box like fishnet in ArcGIS 10.2.

Everything, works fine. However, at output there is no .prj file, although spatial reference was defined at the tool.

How can I modify the script to get a .prj file in output according to defined spatial reference?

I used following function to define spatial reference and finally used fishnet to make the grid.

```
spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameter(2)

arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(outFeatureClass, originCoordinate, yAxisCoordinate, cellSizeWidth, cellSizeHeight, numRows, numColumns, oppositeCoorner, labels, templateExtent, geometryType)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined your spatial reference. Your tool has passed a spatial reference object to your script as a parameter, but you script does not *do* anything with it. Simply passing it to your script does not define the spatial reference.

2 options:

- Don't pass a spatial reference. Instead set the Output Coordinate System in the Environments... ->  Output Coordinates dialog when you run your tool.

[image: environment.png]

- Pass a spatial reference as you do now, then use it in your code to set the Output Coordinate System environment:

  `arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.GetParameter(2)`

Comment: You are right. There's no need to pass the Spatial reference. your second option works better for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

PRJ files define the projection of the shapefile. To create one define the projection in ArcCatalog either by using the tool [Define Projection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) or right click on the layer and select properties (there's a whole dialog there).

It would also be sufficient to copy the prj file from your input and rename it to match the shape file.

Considering you're doing this as part of a tool I'd go with define projection...

```
# get spatial reference from an existing object
desc = arcpy.Describe(InputData)
SR = desc.spatialReference

# set the spatial reference of a feature class
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outFeatureClass,SR)
```

I notice your script has `spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameter(2)`, there may be problems with that.. perhaps you should be using `spatial_ref = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)` or there may be problems with the definition. I generally use `sys.argv[n]` to access parameters I don't experience problems there. Check to see if your spatial reference is an object:

```
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(28355) # one for example
print type(SR)
<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.SpatialReference'>
print len(SR)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'SpatialReference' has no len()
```

Where defining as text:

```
SR = "PROJCS['GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0],UNIT['Degree',0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000],PARAMETER['False_Northing',10000000],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',147],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0],UNIT['Meter',1]]"
print type(SR)
<type 'str'>
print len(SR)
396
```

To ensure that your spatial reference as passed contains a value, if it's a string check the length of the string to ensure it's not `''`

Comment: my spatial_ref is a object, as I used {GetParameter} in stead of {GetParameterAsText}. My understanding was, if i chose spatial_ref as a object, it should have a .prj file in output automatically. unfortunately, it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure when you could use GetParameter, I am fairly sure that the toolbox passes everything as text. Perhaps somebody that knows will elaborate on when to use GetParameter instead of GetParameterAsText.

Comment: GetParameter return an Object, where GetParameterAsText return String. I solved the issue with an extra line of code. {arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = spatial_ref}